# How to find Gmail mailboxes in other languages

Tags: gmail, imap

I need to select the 'Sent' and 'Spam' folders in Gmail, but I have an account that does not work. I've found out later that the folders are in non-English language, but it doesn't seem to represent the unicode characters of those language either. Does anybody know how to find out which one is the 'Sent' or 'Spam' folder of a Gmail account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **XLIST** command, Google and Apple developed a special IMAP command **XLIST** to address this issue.

IMAP XLIST command returns a list of folders and their well-know flags (\Inbox, \Drafts, \Trash, \Sent, \Spam).

[Localized gmail imap folders](http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/localized-gmail-imap-folders/)

Answer (score -1):

see the link below for help:

[Encode::IMAPUTF7](http://metacpan.org/pod/Encode%3a%3aIMAPUTF7)

Comment: Link only answer.

Answer (score -1):

For searching in Spam folfer (no matter the language of your account) write "is:spam" (without the quotes) in the search box. For searching Sent e-mails, just write "is:sent". You have more conbinations, such as "is:unread" (my favourite), "label:work", etc.

Hope it hepls.

Comment: `is:sent` is not listed as a search operator in the [Gmail help article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=es) about search operators.

Comment: It works, and you can find the command explained in several webs, i.e. https://www.askdavetaylor.com/search-sent-messages-google-gmail/ or http://smallbusiness.chron.com/limit-gmail-search-sent-mail-box-43552.html

Comment: Why to rely on unofficial sources when there is an official source that states a couple of operator that do the same?

Comment: By the other hand, and most important, after reading the accepted answer it looks that this answer doesn't answer the question.